# Why does my Hyper-V VM gets new IP ever day?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, dns

I have a VM that is unreachable every new day, because it got a new IP in a other subnet i believe (other subnet mask ie 255.255.0.0 instead of 255.255.255.0). What could be the cause of this. I'm running Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.

Things complicating this setup is that the router acts as a DNS and a DHCP and the server also acts as a DNS. All the workstations and servers are configured to choose the Server (192.168.1.6) as the primary DNS.

What could be the reason for this problem?

IP numbers:

- 192.168.1.1 is the router
- 192.168.1.6 is the server
- 192.168.1.78 is the hyper-v host

[image: network map]

Below: The IP settings for the Hyper-V host and the VMs share the same except for the IP address.
[image: Hyper-V Host IP Settings]

I wanted to post the question on serverfault but don't have the points for the picture.

Comment: Does the Hyper-V get IP's from DHCP?

Comment: Yes it does. When its all going as planned the DNS (and DHCP?) is the Server with the AD.

Answer (score 1):

You could have two DCHP servers running, or your DHCP server is slow in responding to renewal requests and the VM:s switch to APIPA addresses.